# Publication only for the site administrator in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, content-management-system, crud

to making a simple and practically static application, with the pages of: Home, About Me, Services but in fact I need an ***article*** page where all the articles and their show existed, but the owner of the site (admin) will publish the articles and then make a pdf available for download, right after each post. the user will not take any action, just read and download the article. my doubt is, i need to create a model but just wouldn’t do any **CRUD** action? I think about doing **CRUD**, but as if it were private, just so he can do it as needed, but I'm not sure. (About PDF I found some jewels about it, is there anything to indicate to me? Thanks !!!

Comment: Yes you need some CRUD to handle it and some roles and authentication mechanism to have your admin (and only him) have the ability to publish articles and your users to only read them.

Comment: thank you so much for answering me, but do you have any idea how i can do this? is it a private method? I didn't find it in the documents, do you know where I can find something to support me ???

Comment: You can begin by having a special route (say your_app/admin) that pops up a login. If the user is authenticated and is admin, you have the article add/edit/delete and pdf generation. You have ready solutions for that https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_admin_interfaces but you will have to learn how to use them of course.

Comment: You can also easily just build it yourself, but as for the authentication part (is the user authorized / an admin?) that's generally not something ideally built yourself, go with a gem like devsie

Comment: thank you very much, I was thinking about it all day. I'm still a beginner, but you helped me a lot. good weekend my friend! thanks

Comment: What you are describing is basically a simple Content Management System (CMS). Besides CRUD the question really touches on two different broad concepts - the first is *authentication* (identifying users) the second is *authorization* which is the set of buisness logic which determines who can do what. For authentication Devise is the most popular solution in Rails. For authorization you can use gems like Pundit or CanCanCan.